# Parse text file into dictionary C# <string> <int>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code that is not working for parsing a text file to a dictionary...

```
 Dictionary<string, int> dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // This dictionary will get rid of pipe delimited comp codes, get distinct, and keep cuont of how many DSD records per Comp Code

        if (LineToStartOn.pInt > 0)
        {
           using (var sr = new StreamReader("\\rvafiler1\rdc\clients\sams\pif\DSD_Dictionary.txt"))
            {
               string line = null;
               string key = null;
               int value = 0;

               // while it reads a key
               while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // add the key and whatever it 
                    // can read next as the value
                    dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode.Add(key, sr.ReadBlock);
                    dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode.Add(value, sr.ReadBlock());
                }
            }
        }
```

The last line is where it fails. It does not like the dictionay.Add(Line, sr.ReadBlock()) statements. Where am I going wrong?

I need to read in a string followed by an int,.

Comment: because you have define dictionary as <string, int> and sr.ReadLine() returns string, not int

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to count the number of occurrences of the same line in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is declared as `<string, int>` but the second value you are adding is another string (from sr.ReadLine)  I think you want a dictionary of `<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to make it as follows:

Where your key is line number 
and your string is your line;

```
 var dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode = new Dictionary<int, string>(); // This dictionary will get rid of pipe delimited comp codes, get distinct, and keep cuont of how many DSD records per Comp Code

        if (LineToStartOn.pInt > 0)
        {
           using (var sr = new StreamReader("\\rvafiler1\rdc\clients\sams\pif\DSD_Dictionary.txt"))
            {
                string line = null;
                int lineNumber = 1;

                // while it reads a key
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()) )
                {
                    // add the key and whatever it 
                    // can read next as the value
                    dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode.Add(lineNumber++, line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am actually needing to read a string/int combination. The string represents a code and the int represents the number of times I have read that code. This is added into the dictionary further on in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

[Using StreamReader to count duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079298/using-streamreader-to-count-duplicates)

```
Dictionary<string, int> firstNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (string name in YourListWithNames)
{
   if (!firstNames.ContainsKey(name))
      firstNames.Add(name, 1);
   else
      firstNames[name] += 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a line as a key and subsequent number from file as a value, it should look like this:

```
           string key = null;
           int value = 0;

           // while it reads a key
           while ((key = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //read subsequent value
                value = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                //put a key/value pair to dictionary
                dictDSDRecordsByValidCompCode.Add(key, value);
            }
```